# Travis running all schemes but only want a few to run

Tags: swift, xcode, travis-ci, xcodebuild

I have three schemes in my Xcode project

- Gradient-iOS (Framework target)
- Gradient-macOS (Framework target)
- Gradient-Demo (App target)

The following isn't working on Travis.

```
language: swift
xcode_project: Gradient.xcodeproj
osx_image: xcode9.3
xcode_sdk: iphonesimulator11.3
xcode_scheme:
 - Gradient-iOS
 - Gradient-macOS

script: 
 - xcodebuild clean build
```

All of the schemes run. The scheme `Gradient-Demo` fails with code-signing related issues. I don't want to fix it. I just don't want that scheme to run at all.

I don't understand why the App target is running. I only want the above two Framework targets to build.

Any advice?